# websecurity.createuserandaccount sqlexception

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, sqlexception

When I attempt to create an account in my app, it throws an SQL exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column
>   'UserName', table ''; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

This is my register function

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    db.Users.Add(new User {
                        UserName = model.UserName,
                        FullName = model.FullName
                    });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View("Register","_RegisterLayout",model);
        }
```

Clearly I am passing the required `model.UserName` and `model.Password` to the function but it still keeps throwing error saying it cannot accept NULL values.

Below is my global `Application_Start()`

```
if(!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "UserName", "FullName", autoCreateTables:true );
```

This is my register model

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,12}",ErrorMessage="Username must consist of between 3 and 12 characters (only letters, numbers, dashes, and underscores allowed)")]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your action.  Inspect the value of model.UserName.  Just because you pass it in, doesn't mean it is not null.  In fact, it probably is.

Comment: Thanks but I do receive the values inside the function .. Even if I hard code the parameters i get an exception

Comment: Inspect what is in the DB's cache -- my bet is there is another user somewhere you are trying to save as well when you call save changes.

Comment: @WyattBarnett: Good point.  I'm very used to the (correct) pattern of grabbing a fresh `db` in the controller action.  Here, `db` seems to already be instantiated elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. But this application crashes even before db.savechanges gets called. In fact it crashs @                     WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password); complaining about inserting null values into UserName column. and btw db is initialized in the same controller above all these lines.